# ¿Cómo pasar de letra/numero en C?

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con un programa que he hecho ya que siempre me da el mismo resultado y no utiliza las funciones `scanf` que hay puestas después de elegir la elección entre numero o letra. Si alguien es muy amable de resolverme el problema seria de gran ayuda

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int numero;
    char letra;
    int eleccion;
    int numerador=128;

    printf("dime si quieres un numero o una letra\n");
    printf("1 es para numeros y 2 es para letras\n");
    scanf("%d",&eleccion);

    if(eleccion==1){
        printf("dime el numero que tu quieras\n");
        scanf("%d",&numero);

        while(numero > 0){
            if(numero >= numerador){
                printf(" 1 ");
                numero = numero - numerador;
                numerador = numerador/2;
            }
            else{
                printf(" 0 ");
                numerador = numerador / 2;
            }
        }

        while(numerador>=1){
            printf(" 0 ");
            numerador = numerador / 2;
        }
    }
    else if(eleccion==2){
        printf("dime la letra que tu quieras\n");
        scanf("%c",&letra);

        while(letra > 0){
            if(letra >= numerador){
                printf(" 1 ");
                letra = letra - numerador;
                numerador = numerador/2;
            }
            else{
                printf(" 0 ");
                numerador = numerador / 2;
            }
        }

        while(numerador >= 1){
            printf(" 0 ");
            numerador = numerador / 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Es en `scanf` para coger el numero o la letra que no me los detecta y me hace el numero 10 en binario. ¿Alguien sabe lo que pasa?

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que debe hacer tu programa cuando se eligen números? ¿Y cuando se eligen letras?

Comment: Date cuenta que `(resuelto)`  aquí no significa nada. Las preguntas deben tener una respuesta marcada como solución para darse por finalizadas. Como has comentado que ya has localizado el error, te sugeriría escribir la respuesta correspondiente y marcarla como solución o, directamente, eliminar la pregunta. Por favor, ayuda a mantener [es.so] en buen estado

Answer (score 1):

El programa funciona correctamente, otra cosa es que no haga lo que tu esperas:

- Si eliges un número, el programa saca su representación binaria.
- Si eliges una letra, el programa coge la representación decimal del caracter e imprime su representación binaria.

En cualquier caso ambas representaciones binarias están al revés. Falta invertirlas para obtener la secuencia real.

Ignoro cual es el comportamiento esperado del programa, pero como ves hace exactamente lo que has programado. Quedo a la espera de que respondas a mi comentario (editando la pregunta y añadiendo la información que falta), para finalizar esta respuesta.

PD.: Esto no lo he puesto en un comentario porque entonces no sería legible.

Comment: gracias por la información pero ya está resuelto el problema, solo faltaba poner fflush(stdin) después de que elegir la opción de numero o letra

Comment: @Infinity Si la pregunta ya no tiene sentido te sugiero eliminarla. Así evitarás además recibir votos negativos al estar la pregunta incompleta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es %c ya que como es una entrada del usuario en realidad se te devuelve char * (Una cadena completa EJ. caracter escrito + caracter de fin de cadena) por lo que si quieres obtener la letra en realidad el formato es %s

Intentalo:

```
printf("dime la letra que tu quieras\n");
scanf("%s",&letra);
printf("la letra es %s ",&letra);
```

Comment: Se agradecería que probases tus respuestas antes de publicar. Usar `%s` sobre un `char` solo sirve para que tu programa, en el mejor de los casos, sea asesinado por el Sistema Operativo para evitar que corrompa memoria que no le pertenece